# str() method on numpy array and back

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, string-literals

Is there any built-in method to get back `numpy` array after applying `str()` method, for example,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]])
a_str = str(a)

#to get back a?
a = some_method(a_str).
```

Following two methods don't work:

```
from ast import literal_eval
a = literal_eval(a_str)  # Error

import numpy as np
a = np.fromstring(a_str)  # Error
```

Update 1:
Unfortunatelly i have very big data already converted with `str()` method so I connot reconvert it with some other method.

Comment: Really, you should avoid this where possible. But I have updated with a solution which reverses `str` output.

Comment: Does that big data string include ellipsis (...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issues seem to be separators and newlines characters. You can use [`np.array2string`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html) and [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to resolve them:

```
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval

a = np.array([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]])

a_str = ''.join(np.array2string(a, separator=',').splitlines())

# '[[ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [ 4.4, 5.5, 6.6]]'

b = np.array(literal_eval(a_str))

# array([[ 1.1,  2.2,  3.3],
#        [ 4.4,  5.5,  6.6]])
```

Note that *without* any arguments `np.array2string` behaves like `str`.

---

If your string is given and unavoidable, you can use this hacky method:

```
a_str = str(a)
res = np.array(literal_eval(''.join(a_str.replace('\n', ' ').replace('  ', ','))))

array([[ 1.1,  2.2,  3.3],
       [ 4.4,  5.5,  6.6]])
```

---

As per @hpaulj's comment, one benefit of `np.array2string` is ability to specify `threshold`. For example, consider a string representation of `x = np.arange(10000)`.

- `str(x)` will return ellipsis, e.g. `'[   0    1    2 ..., 9997 9998 9999]'`
- `np.array2string(x, threshold=11e3)` will return the complete string

Comment: The `threshhold` also limits the usefulness of `str`.

Comment: [numpy array2string applied on huge array, skips central values, ( … in the middle )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144127/numpy-array2string-applied-on-huge-array-skips-central-values-in-the-mid)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `repr`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]])
a_str = repr(a)
b = eval("np." + repr(a))
print(repr(a))
print(repr(b))
```

Comment: @jpp `ast.literal_eval` is too safe to be useful.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin @jpp i have updated the question, i cannot use `repr()` or other methods, question is specific by using only `str()` mehod.